# SuiteCRM : How to Add Dashlet which renders external project

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

Anybody knows how to create dashlet that render an external app in suiteCRM/sugarCRM ?

Thanx.

Comment: Probably lots of people, but that's not the right way to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SuiteCRM**:

What you need to do is create your module using `module builder`. Then edit the default dashlet  see `modules/your_module/Dashlets/your_module_name/your_module_name.php.`

You need to override the `display()` so that it returns the code that you wish to use. Typically you would return the HTML from an external file.

```
    function display()
    {
        $path = 'modules/your_module_name/Dashlets/your_module_name/your_module_name.html';
        parent::display();
        return file_get_contents($path);
    }
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, I want to get my app as module, I mean when a client want to add my external project in the dashboard he can find it as module ( even if it's not a suiteCrm module ) I did some modifications on addDashlet.tpl, I added after div #moduledashlet loop a new row to my table which contains what i want but it seems not really professional. I want to add it from module or dashlet iframe or something like that.
Regards.

Comment: You shouldn't be changing the add dashlet template. Please see my solution above.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Daniel, what I want is this $path should be something external to my CRM for example It could be something like : localhost:port/myexternalproject/myExternalFolder/myExternalfile.html

Comment: file_get_contents lets you do exactly that - file_get_contents("http://yourappaddress");

Comment: Why you use custom dashboard if you need to display external page ?

Answer (score 1):

you can configure a new dashboard in suitecrm and while adding new dashboard, select "Web" type of dashboard and enter URL of you external app there. SuiteCRM will load this in iframe. Give it a try and let me know if you face any issue.

Creating new module and custom dashboard is to much work for something which is already available in suiteCRM.